# CSS style changes on window resize

Tags: html, css

I dont know why the size of the header and footer changes on window resize. On debugging / rewriting the code, I found that on adding the `Setting`(css:setting-dropdown) or `Logout` (css:logout-button) div, the CSS breaks. I have tried to fix it but I am unable to figure out the reason why the settings and logout buttons display outside the header width and why the width of header and footer increases on adding those 2 divs.

Thanks for the help

```css
html { 
  background: url("backlines.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
    height: 850px;
}

.averios-header {
 position: absolute;
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,color-stop(0, rgb(226, 226, 226)),color-stop(0, rgb(254, 254, 254)),color-stop(0.1, rgb(254, 254, 254)),color-stop(1, rgb(219, 219, 219)),color-stop(1, rgb(209, 209, 209)));
 left: 1px;
 top: 0px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 /*overflow: auto;*/
 box-shadow: 0px 2px;
}

div#averios-logo{
 width: 300px;
 margin-left:270px;
}

div#loginHeader {
 font-family:'Museo Slab 700';
    margin-top: 360px;
    margin-left: 276px;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: rgba(0, 173, 239, 1);
}

div#underLoginHeader {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 278px;
    font-size: 25px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}
.averios-footer {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 100%, 0% 0%,color-stop(0, rgb(226, 226, 226)),color-stop(0, rgb(254, 254, 254)),color-stop(0, rgb(254, 254, 254)),color-stop(0, rgb(254, 254, 254)),color-stop(0.176, rgb(254, 254, 254)),color-stop(0.904, rgb(219, 219, 219)),color-stop(1, rgb(209, 209, 209)));
    margin-top: 812px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    margin-left: -7px;
    overflow: auto;
}
/*div#header-hr {
 position: absolute;
 background: rgba(0, 173, 239, 1);
 height: 6px;
 width: 100%;
}*/

div#footer-hr {
 position: absolute;
 background: rgba(0, 173, 239, 1);
 height: 6px;
 width: 100%;
}

div#footer-text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 280px;
 color: rgb(127,130,134);
}

div#forgot-password-link {
    margin-top: 90px;
    font-size: 23px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a {
    color: rgb(127,130,134);
}

div#welcome-text {
    margin-left: 276px;
    font-family: 'Museo Slab 300';
    font-size: 22px;
}

div#welcome-text p {
    margin: 5px auto;
}

div#dropdown-pulse #dropbutton {
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 276px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    background: rgba(0, 173, 239, 1);
    color: white;
    width: 230px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    text-align: left;
}

img#arrow {
    position: relative;
    top: 110px;
    right: 84px;
}

img#sphere {
    position: relative;
    top: 116px;
    right: 51px;
}

/* SETTING DROPDOWN */

div#setting-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 1350px;
 height: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
}


div#setting-dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    background: rgba(0, 173, 239, 1);
    width: 237px;
    /* padding: 8px; */
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -116px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 15px;
}
div#setting-dropdown p {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-top: 44px;
    font-family: 'Museo Slab 700';
}

img#setting-blue-arrow {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 121px;
    top: -44px;
}

div#setting-dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* display: none; */
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: 'Museo Slab 300';
    padding: 2px;
}

#setting-dropdown:hover #setting-dropdown-content {
 display:block;
}

/* SOMETHING NEW */

div#setting-dropdown i {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

div#setting-dropdown:hover i {
    background-color: rgba(0, 173, 239, 1);
 color:white;
}

div#logout-button {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 1569px;
    margin-top: -90px;
    border-style: none;
}

button#averios-logout {
    background : rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
    width: 135px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: 'Museo Slab 700';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="averios.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dropdown.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" />
 
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="averios-header">
 <div id="setting-dropdown">
  <!-- SETTING DROPDOWN WILL GO HERE -->
  <p> SETTINGS <i class="ion-chevron-down"></i></p>
  <div id="setting-dropdown-content">
   <a href="#">Change Password</a>
   <a href="#">Change Security Settings</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="averios-logo">
  <img src="averioslogo.png" width="176" height="129">
 </div>
 <div id="logout-button">
  <button id="averios-logout"> LOGOUT </button>
 </div>
</div>

<footer class="averios-footer">
<div id="footer-hr">
</div>
 <div id="footer-text">
  &copy; 2016, All Rights Reserved.
 </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check this link:-http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_resizeto

Comment: @Raziasultana I dont want to write a script for that yet, I want to see what is wrong with my CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple example of your code.  I have changed your html structure and change lots of css. Please take a look. I have also added media query for better view. If you have any question ask me in comment. For better understanding you can learn about positioning [CSS POSITIONING](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) And a basic example of [Responsive Top Nav](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav) . Good luck :)

```css
/*UseFull Class*/

.img-responsive {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}


/*Main CSS  Start*/
html {
  background: red no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

/*Header Section*/

.averios-header {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, color-stop(0, rgb(226, 226, 226)), color-stop(0, rgb(254, 254, 254)), color-stop(0.1, rgb(254, 254, 254)), color-stop(1, rgb(219, 219, 219)), color-stop(1, rgb(209, 209, 209)));
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px;
}

div#averios-logo {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

div.right_menu {
  float: right;
}

ul#setting-dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

ul#setting-dropdown li a {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'Museo Slab 700';
}

div#setting-dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 173, 239, 1);
  min-width: 237px;
  right: 0;
  top: 44px;
}

div#setting-dropdown-content a {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: 'Museo Slab 300';
}

ul#setting-dropdown:hover #setting-dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

i.ion-chevron-down {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 7px 22px 5px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

ul#setting-dropdown:hover i {
  background-color: rgba(0, 173, 239, 1);
  color: white;
}

span#logout-button {
  border-style: none;
}

button#averios-logout {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
  width: 135px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: 'Museo Slab 700';
}


/*Content Area*/

/*Footer Area*/

.averios-footer {
  position: absolute;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 100%, 0% 0%, color-stop(0, rgb(226, 226, 226)), color-stop(0, rgb(254, 254, 254)), color-stop(0, rgb(254, 254, 254)), color-stop(0, rgb(254, 254, 254)), color-stop(0.176, rgb(254, 254, 254)), color-stop(0.904, rgb(219, 219, 219)), color-stop(1, rgb(209, 209, 209)));
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 65px;
}

div#footer-hr {
  background: rgba(0, 173, 239, 1);
  height: 6px;
  width: 100%;
}

div#footer-text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 19px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(127, 130, 134);
}


/*Responsive Media Query*/

@media only screen and (max-width:521px) {
  div#averios-logo {
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 150px;
  }
  ul#setting-dropdown li a {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  div#setting-dropdown-content a {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  button#averios-logout {
    border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:390px) {
  div#averios-logo {
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 100px;
  }
  ul#setting-dropdown li a {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  div#setting-dropdown-content a {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  button#averios-logout {
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="averios-header">
  <div id="averios-logo">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/O/v/c/b/i/6/generic-logo-hi.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="right_menu">
    <!-- SETTING DROPDOWN WILL GO HERE -->
    <ul id="setting-dropdown">

      <li> <a href="#">SETTINGS <i class="ion-chevron-down"></i> </a></li>
      <div id="setting-dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Change Password</a>
        <a href="#">Change Security Settings</a>
      </div>

    </ul>

    <span id="logout-button">
        <button id="averios-logout"> LOGOUT </button>
      </span>

  </div>
</div>
<!--header End-->

<footer class="averios-footer">
  <div id="footer-hr">
  </div>
  <div id="footer-text">
    &copy; 2016, All Rights Reserved.
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is too big margin to be able to fit resolution less than 1600px

```
div#logout-button {
    margin-left: 1569px;
}
div#setting-dropdown {
    margin-left: 1350px;
}
```

Don`t You want to consider to fix position of those elements with "right: value;" style parameter? or using "float:right;" for both elements?

Comment: "right:value" does solve the issue of buttons being out of header but I still have extra space on the left side, (I took out the margin-left's), any idea how that can be fixed?

Comment: there is another margin 
div#averios-logo{
 width: 300px;
 margin-left:270px;
}

Comment: @Mani lot's of positing issue and margin-left is the main problem. And also you can change the view if you change the html structure too. OR you can write media query for small screen.

Comment: BTW You`re setting image width in CSS and HTML both (like it was used to be in old HTML)

Comment: @MostafaBaezid Thank you for the input, I am fairly new to CSS and dont have alot of experience yet so I try to fit the elements however I can. I understand your point but could you please give an example of what you said. Thaks

Comment: @Mani sure I can. So you want a header which image takes left and those settings and logout takes right  on header?

Comment: basically I want to fit all the things(setting and logout) in one header(with image), which does not go out of width. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: @Mani [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/7pqfgr41/ ]  Just give you a basic example. Right now busy time. will upload small code soon.

Answer (score -1):

I checked your code. There is have so many problem. So, I suggestion to you use bootsrap framework. You need to write so many css code, bootstrap doing this for you.

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)